# Pass values from the main window to another window

Tags: javascript

in my script the user enters text in the main window, then using the control that I have attached below, the text entered in the first window (by the user) is transferred to the second window.
In the second window, the text entered by the user must blink.
My problem is: how do I make blink the text in the second window?

```
if (currentElementContent.length)   
{         
    var newWindow = window.open("ex.html","Nuova finestra","width=300,height=300 ,toolbar=yes, location=no,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=no,resizable=no");                 
    newWindow.document.write(currentElementContent);    
}
```

Comment: Have you considered the localStorage API?

Comment: You would need a script to make the text blink (e.g. do an animation)- assuming you're not going to use the long deprecated `<blink>` tag.  Since the new window is the same domain and you have the window handle, you can use a script from either window.  For design clarity, I'd probably load a script into the new window (create a script tag and insert it) that could run the animation.  Is your question more a case of "how to I make text blink with an animation"?  Or is it how do I do modify content in another window?  Which issue are you looking for help with?

Comment: I can't make blink the text in the second window, I don't know how to do this.
I repeat that the user inserts the text from the first window, and then is passed to the second window.
Honestly, I don't care approcciarsi the great technologies would be fine even blink, I'm interested in solving the problem.

Comment: http://www.antiyes.com/jquery-blink-plugin

Comment: You want to know how to pass data to the other window or only how to let blink the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to pass data to another window

A great way is to use `postMessage` API which works in most recent browsers (i tested Chrome right now.)

```
newWindow.postMessage("The string you want to pass", "*");
```

> **"The string you want to pass"**: Is the object you want to pass, all browsers support for now only Strings.
>
> *****: Is the origin; from who is this message?

In the other window register for a `message` event.

```
function listener(event)
{
    // e.origin => origin
    // e.data => is the object (string) passed to it

    document.getElementById('testi').innerHTML += event.data + "<br/>";
}

if (window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener("message", listener, false);    
}
else
{
    attachEvent("message", listener);
}
```

> **event.data**: Is the string which has been passed
>
> **event.origin**: Is the origin of the message

`attachEvent` is used by IE.

---

### How to let blink the text [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wM6qG/1/)

I'm pretty sure jQuery can do it for you in a better way but anyway, to let your text blink you could make it visible/invisible every `X` milliseconds using a timer (interval).

In your `ex.html` start an interval which every 250 ms (or less, or more) will change the visiblity of a span (or div if you want or everything you want)

Example:

```
<span id="text">Text</span>
```

Then the script would be

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var isVisible = true;
setInterval(function()
{
  if (isVisible) {
    text.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "";
  }
  isVisible = !isVisible;
}, 250);
```

---

```
setInterval(function, repeat)
```

> **function**: Is the code block which will be executed every **repeat** milliseconds.
>
> **repeat**: Is the milliseconds of wait between the two executions.

A working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wM6qG/1/)